# Ambiguous answer for simple integral involving Dirac delta function

Tags: calculus, integration, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Are both of these answers to the following integral correct:

\begin{equation}
\int_0^1\int_0^1dx_1 dx_2\delta(1-x_1-x_2)\overset{?}{=} 1\text{ or }\sqrt{2}
\end{equation}

I can "justify" that the integral is equal to $1$ by using the following property of the delta function

\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1dx_1 dx_2\delta(1-x_1-x_2)f(x_1,x_2)&=\int_0^1dx_1f(x_1,1-x_1)\\
&=\int_0^1 dx_1\\
&=1
\end{align}
where I used that our function is just $f(x_1,x_2)=1$ in the second equality.

However I can also justify that the integral is equal to $\sqrt{2}$, as if you draw the region in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that the delta function localizes the integrand on, namely the line $x_2=1-x_1$ (shown in orange in the figure) you see that the orange line segment has length $\sqrt{2}$. More precisely, I could argue that the integrand secretly contains $\sqrt{g}=1$ where $g$ is the determinant of the $g_{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 &1\end{pmatrix}$ metric. Then if I pull-back this $\sqrt{g}$ onto the line segment I get a factor of $\sqrt{2}$; i.e. take the parametric curve $(x_1,x_2)=(\tau,1-\tau)$ for $\tau\in [0,1]$ then $g_{\tau\tau}=\frac{d x^{\mu}}{d\tau}\frac{d x^{\nu}}{d\tau}g_{\mu\nu}=2$ so $\sqrt{g_{\tau\tau}}=\sqrt{2}$.

*Are both answers correct because one needs to specify whether one is integrating over $\mathbb{R}^2$ with or without a metric?*[[image: Dirac delta function localizes integrand onto the orange curve <span class=]$x_2=1-x_1$ which has length $\sqrt{2}$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFqXp.png)

Comment: Only the first is 'correct' in the sense that integrating a $\delta$ distribution is more a formal thing than an actual integration, and, as you have it above, applies only to one dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a change of coordinates
$$x_{\pm}~:=~x_1\pm x_2 $$
(with [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) $=2$) is instructive:

$$\begin{align}I ~=~&\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\!\mathrm{d}x_1~\mathrm{d}x_2~\theta(0\!\leq\! x_1\!\leq\! 1)~ \delta (1\!-\!x_1\!-\!x_2)\cr
~=~&\frac{1}{2}\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\!\mathrm{d}x_+~\mathrm{d}x_-~\theta(0\!\leq\! x_+\!+\!x_-\!\leq\! 2)~ \delta (1\!-\!x_+)\cr
~=~&\frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\!\mathrm{d}x_-~\theta(-1\!\leq\! x_-\!\leq\! 1) \cr
~=~& 1. \end{align}  $$
Here $\theta$ denotes the [indicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function)/[characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function) function.